# add rss newsreel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, rss

So I found an rss based newsreel slideshow that I really like. Is there a way to put that same newsreel on my website so that it gets updated automatically by their server?  I've found the `<link>` element in the head section that traces the newsreel back to the original rss.  Does that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I understand. Personally, I got about it this way. Get the RSS feed, stick it into YQL Consol, get the JSONP URL then use jQuery to parse it like so:

```
$.ajax({
    //YQL JSON URL
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%2Cdescription%2Clink%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usgs.gov%2Frss%2Fnews_description.xml%22&format=json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc',
    success: function(data) {
        //narrow down WHAT you want
        var results = data.query.results.item;
        //loop through results and then append each item to #listnews selector.                 
        $.each(results, function(index, data) {
            $("#listnews").append("<li><a href='" + results[index].link + "'>" + results[index].title + "</a></li>");
        });
    }
});​
```

Here is a jsfiddle working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qpkpn/

I have found this works in all current browsers also... plus IE8  (i was having an issue in IE8 until jQuery JSON parse saved the day)

Add this to your body area:

```
<ul id="loadnews"></ul>
```

You will then need to add a scrolling function of some sort to it.

I have seen a ticker called jTicker that might work for you also.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was unable to make it work though because the rss I was using was hosted on feedburner and I'm not sure if it's a problem with the feedburner site or the code.  Most likely the feedburner site since the answer this one references had rave reviews

Comment: @user1634292 Can you post the RSS feed for us to look at?

Comment: I emailed the website manager and got the url for the actual rss feed but it's still not working.  When I save the .xml file to the directory it works, but when I link to it online, it doesn't work.  Any ideas? This is the feed I'd like to use http://www.usgs.gov/rss/news_description.xml

Comment: check out my revised answer above. you were probably running into cross domain issues. using yql and jsonp can help with that.

Comment: Thanks for spending so much time on this! The fiddle was very helpful! I had never even heard of yql before, I'll have to learn more about that.